# headerfile inclusion in pure virtual classes

Tags: c++

If I have a pure virtual class like the following:

I have class structure like the following:

```
class interface_class {
    virtual void someFunction(MyClassA& a) = 0;
    virtual void someFunction(MyClassB& b) = 0;
}
```

What is the correct way to include MyClassA/MyClassB? Should I do some forward declaration in the header file of the interface class and do the real inclusion in the header file of the implemention, or should I include the header file of MyClassA/B directly in the interface class?

Comment: On a side note you'd want to pass 'a' and 'b' by const reference (ie. `f(const MyClassA& a)`) as soon as your classes become large and/or complex to copy. It will be easier to use forward declarations from there.

Comment: thx, i forgot the & for the references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Forward Declarations for both the classes.
In fact always use forward declarations wherever you can.
Using forward declarations saves you compilation time & also restricts you from creating unneeded dependencies.

Comment: Note that you have to change the parameters to be pointers or references in order to use a forward declaration.

Comment: @BjörnPollex: Not really.You are allowed to *declare* functions which accept or return *Incomplete types*.

Comment: if i do a forward declaration in the header file of the implementation then I have to include the header in the cpp file, don't I? Is this the common way, to include headers only in cpp files?

Comment: @JamesBrown147: You need to include the header file in the cpp files because your cpp file will need to access the internals(members) of the forward declared class and the compiler has no way to know the definition of a class unless you include the header, so it complain with an error if you don't do so.Yes this is the correct way to do this.

Comment: ok, because I always thought that all the inclusions should be placed in the header file and the cpp file only includes its header.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a forward declaration in a separate header file.

That is you have your current header files with the definition of `MyClassA` and `MyClassB`. You'll need to group classes used at the same time and create a new header file like this:

file `MyClassesFwd.h` (naming convention up to you)

```
namespace XX {
     class MyClassA;
     class MyClassB;
}
```

Your interface header:

```
#include <MyClassesFwd.h>
// ... your interface definition ...
```

An actual source file will look like this on the other hand:

```
#include <MyClassA.h>
#include <MyClassB.h>
#include <MyInterface.h>
```

This will prevent you from rewriting the forward declaration everytime.